# Block size and transaction per block in Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain

What is the relationship between MaxMessageCount, AbsoluteMaxBytes, and PreferredMaxBytes?

A block in fabric consists of a MaxMessageCount number of transaction or PreferredMaxBytes?

What should be the value of these to get maximum throughput?

Answer (score 4):

**Max Message Count**: The maximum number of transactions/messages to permit in block.

**Absolute Max Bytes**: The (strict) maximum number of bytes allowed for serialized transactions/messages in a block.

**Preferred Max Bytes**: The preferred maximum number of bytes allowed the serialized transactions/messages in a batch. A transaction/message larger than the preferred max bytes will result in a batch larger than preferred max bytes.

The criteria that is encountered first will be taken into consideration while the orderer cuts the block.

If you have a constantly flowing high number of transactions, then pack as many transactions as possible in a block to get max throughput. Otherwise tweak the **BatchTimeout** and **MaxMessageCount** to optimize your transaction throughput.

If you want to dig deep on this aspect refer to this research paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1805.11390.pdf